# Turn jquery ajax call into React axios call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm having an issue setting up a axios call in React. I've got it working using Jquery in javascript.

Here is my working Jquery code..

```
 $("#btn").on("click", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var filter = $("#IDXT001").val();

    var queryURL =
      "http://api/document?filter=idxt001" + "|" + filter;

    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    }).then(data => {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.map(function(i) {
          return i.Fields.map(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return "<p>" + e.DisplayName + ": " + e.DataValue + "</p>";
          }).join("<br/>");

      }).join('<br/>');
    });
  });
```

So in React, which I'm new too, I have two seperate Api's Im using to create a search form with the first api, and search the database with a second api.

My second api..

```
const filter = "#IDXT001";
  getContracts: function() {
return axios.get(`http://api/ixmasterdocument? 
filter=idxt001|` + filter);
}
```

Here's where my issues are...

```
        loadContracts = () => {
  API.getContracts()
  .then(res => {
    const contracts = res.data;
    console.log(contracts)
    this.setState({ contracts })
  })
}
```

Then trying to render here...

```
  <div className="container">
 {this.state.contracts.map(contract => 
 <p> + {contract.Fields.DisplayName} + ": " + {contract.Fields.DataValue} + 
</p>
 )}
 </div>
```

I need to add a second .map function to map through the Fields array, but not sure where to insert the code for that.
Here is the Fields data I'm trying to pull

```
{Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
0: {Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}
1: {Fields: Array(12), DocImage: {…}}

0:{Id: 0, DisplayName: "Contract #", DataValue: "2222", DataType: "TEXT", 
DataField: "IDXT001"}
```

Comment: can u provide what contracts is and a Field array object

Comment: I added a Fields object. The contracts variable is the array of Fields and DocImage. Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work this way, but I think there could be a "prettier" way. I'm still open to suggestions.

```
  { this.state.contracts.map(contract => <p>{contract.Fields.map( docs => 
     docs.DisplayName + " : " +  docs.DataValue)}</p> )}
```